# Error import - referencing another .java

Tags: java, import, reference

I have two files, one is for administrators another for clients.
Admins one is called: AutocompleteJComboBox
Clients one is called: AutocompleteJComboBox_client

Now when it comes to calling the constructor:

```
StringSearchable searchable_client = new StringSearchable(myWords);
combo_client = new AutocompleteJComboBox(searchable_client);
```

I get this error message:

incompatible types: Practica1.modules.users.client.model.utils.pager.autocomplete.AutocompleteJComboBox_client cannot be converted to Practica1.modules.users.admin.model.utils.pager.autocomplete.AutocompleteJComboBox

Why is giving me the wrong reference?
I've tried to change variables name, .java names, imports and variables related with that process so far.

Comment: Voting to close based on OP's own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If combo_client is declared as AutocompleteJComboBox_client, then it will have to be instantiated as such e.g.

```
StringSearchable searchable_client = new StringSearchable(myWords);
combo_client = new AutocompleteJComboBox_client(searchable_client);
```

Or it may be that it has been wrongly defined as an AutocompleteJComboBox_client and perhaps the code you've posted is correct.

Essentially, you have declared the variable as a particular type and you're trying to create an instance of a different type, which is causing this conflict.